# How to change delimiter/separator of CSV on file.create

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm creating a CSV file using suitescript file.create method. Is there a way to change the delimiter/separator? I'm trying to use pipe(|) instead of comma(,).

I've already tried this

```
var csvFile = file.create({
         name : fileName + '.csv',
         contents: stringValue,
         folder: ****, 
         fileType: file.Type.CSV,
         isonline: true,
         separator: '|'
});
```

It does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to handle the data with commas. You could try enclosing the values with double quotes `""`.

```html
var stringValue = '"A,B", B, C, D';

var fileObj = file.create({
    name : testcsv.csv',
    contents: stringValue,
    folder: xxxx,
    fileType: file.Type.CSV,
    isonline: true
});
```

It should generate like this:

[image]